# Insert an array into another array (perl)

Tags: arrays, perl

Let me start over. I have two arrays that are the lines of two text files. I'm doing some processing on the first array:

1. find a line containing STRING1, and delete it and the line after it. That has been accomplished.
2. find the next line that is just , and insert the entire second array beginning with the line after
3. more when I can do 2. :-)

Comment: If this is about file manipulation, I think you will find that not using arrays is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an array into another using [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @a=qw(a1 a2 a3 a4 <pre> a5 a6); # Let @a be the 1st array
my @b=qw(b1 b2 b3);                # Let @b be the 2nd array

my $index_a; # We will store here the index of the <pre> element from the 1st array
for (0..$#a) { # We iterate through all @a elements to find the position of <pre>
    if ($a[$_] eq '<pre>') {
        $index_a=$_;
        last;
    }
}
if (!defined $index_a) { # Simple validation that we did found a <pre> element
    die "<pre> not found";
}
splice(@a,$index_a,1,@b); # We insert the elements of @b into @a using splice
print join(' ',@a); # This will print "a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 a5 a6"
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no <pre> in the second array. I want the entire 2nd array to be inserted. splice(@a, $index_a, 1, @b); ???

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact question was, but if I understand it right.

```
@array1 =(x, y, <pre>, c, d, e);
@array2 = (f, g, h);
@output = (c, d, e, f, g, h) 

If this is what you want

$element = shift (@array1);
while ($element ne '<pre>') {
      $element = shift (@array1);
}

@output = (@array1, @array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ,It is really hard for me to understand your meaning.It seems that @sam and @psxls have different output and understand about your question. But if it's me , I will use perl [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) function to directly process the file splice.Any way ,it is not hard ,just some simple array operations.

Comment: Not hard for you. Hard for a beginner. :-)

Comment: Well,I am also a beginner,but I think as soon as you can correctly find the perl doc on your question and do as perl doc told you to , problems will be solved.